# Does sql%rowcount attribute work in loop condition?

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowcount

I have written the below program in PL/SQL to insert 5 rows in Students table. As per the loop condition the row count should be 5 but it is showing only 1. Placing DBMS output under the loop also didn't help.

```
DECLARE
    v_input_1 INT;
    v_input_2 VARCHAR2(15);
    v_input_3 VARCHAR2(10);
    v_counter NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN
    v_input_1:= 0;
    v_input_2:= &Type_student_name;
    v_input_3:= &Type_student_class;
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO STUDENTS(id, student_name, student_class)
            VALUES(v_input_1+v_counter, v_input_2, v_input_3);
            v_counter:=v_counter+10;
            EXIT WHEN V_counter > 50;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total rows inserted : '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
        END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total rows inserted : '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

Comment: _"The values of the cursor attributes always refer to the most recently executed SQL statement. The SQL%ROWCOUNT attribute is not related to the state of a transaction."_ Have a look into the oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm

Answer (score 1):

In your example, as you are inserting one row at a time (`insert into ... values ...`), `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is set to 1 in every iteration.

Therefore, it is pretty much useless in this context. Create a local variable and increment it every time (similar to what you're doing with `v_counter`), e.g.

```
declare
  l_cnt number := 0;
begin
  loop
    insert ...
    l_cnt := l_cnt + sql%rowcount;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line('Number of inserted rows = ' || l_cnt);
end;
```

Comment: That would be even better, @Barbaros, for other cases where rows affected isn't 1. Thank you, fixed.